# Basic Filtering in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-filters

Newbie here so please be gentle. I'm having trouble with Angular filters while using data-binded value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

            Insert value to be converted to hexdecimal: <input type="text" ng-model="whatever">

            <h1>{{ whatever }}</h1>

        </div>

        <p>A custom service with a method that converts a given number into a hexadecimal number.</p>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

            app.service('hexafy', function(x) {
                this.myFunc = function (x) {
                    return x.toString(16);
                }
            });
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

            });
            app.filter('myFormat',['hexafy', function(hexafy) {
                return function(x) {
                    return hexafy.myFunc(x);
                };
            }]);
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have trouble with the following line of code :

```
<h1>{{ foo | myFormat }}</h1>
```

Why doesn't it work as intended?

This works :

```
<h1>{{ 255 | myFormat }}</h1>
```

This works as well :

```
<h1>{{ foo }}</h1>
```

Why doesnt't the combinantion of the two work? How do I make it work correctly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error is coming?. You didn't handle undefined value check also

Answer (score 0):

Handle `undefined` value check in custom filter. Value of `foo` is undefined and you call `toString` on that in service `hexafy`.

Updated Filter Code

```
app.filter('myFormat',['hexafy', function(hexafy) {
                return function(x) {
                    if(!x){
                       return x;
                     }
                    return hexafy.myFunc(x);
                };
            }]);
```